# Git local configuration not overwriting global one

Tags: git, git-config

I have several projects using Gitlab and a global configuration (default), as well as a local per-project configuration using another gitlab account.
The problem is that i can't pull on the projects with local configuration, as if the global one was always taken into account.

```
$ git config --global --list
user.name=myusername
user.email=myemail@mydomain.fr
filesystem.Oracle Corporation|1.8.0_162|/dev/disk1s1.timestampresolution=1001 milliseconds
filesystem.Oracle Corporation|1.8.0_162|/dev/disk1s1.minracythreshold=0 nanoseconds

$ git config --local --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.com/folder/project
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.rebase=false
user.name=myotherusername
user.email=myotheremail@myotherdomain.com

$ git pull
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/folder/project.git/' not found
```

Conversely, the project using global conf works just well, in another projects' directory (using global config):

```
$ git pull
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.com/gitlabuser/gitlabproject.git/
Already up to date.
```

Comment: How does `git pull` work with the global configuration for you? the global configuration does not include a `remote.origin.url`
Could you be more clear about what you have tried and what worked?
And what is the output of `git pull https://gitlab.com/folder/project`?

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` is for commit description, not for https service login

Comment: @LinFelix: the output you asked is already in the answer with the fatal error.

Comment: @LeszekMazur: yes so how should i configure my gitlab repository access locally when another global working one is active ?

Comment: @Max what about `git pull https://gitlab.com/folder/project`?

Comment: @Max You can access locally only if you have direct file access. You go to this directory and run git commands in it.